# pyplot.figure() creates and shows figure in PyCharm Debug-Mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I want to plot some values and extract the drawn graph as a numpy-array. My code is working fine when I use the `Run`-Mode in PyCharm(CE 2018.2.3), but when I use the `Debug`-Mode the figure will be shown even though I'm not using `show()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    ...
    dpi = 100
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size / dpi, y_size / dpi), dpi=dpi) #After this line the figure will show up
    ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
    ...
```

I marked the line where the figure will show up in the code-snippet above.
Has anybody an idea how I could block matplotlib from showing the plot/figure? The show up makes debugging impossible.
I already tried to turn inline debugging off but it didn't help.

EDIT:
You have to use a non-interactive backend. This can be done by:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using :

```
plt.close()
```

after `ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])`. Try it out and let me know if it worked.

Comment: It's not working... And the figure is opening after the line before. Also tried `plt.close()` there but didn't help